# Azure Cosmos Table API Rest API $filter InvalidInput

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I am trying to query a Cosmosdb with a Table API with Postman and use OData.

I have a query which works for $top and $select - but returns Invalid Input when I try a filter.

so for the query.

```
https://{{databaseAccount}}.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/Rdm()?$filter=PartitionKey eq '726'
```

I get returned

```
{
    "odata.error": {
        "code": "InvalidInput",
        "message": {
            "lang": "en-us",
            "value": "Request url is invalid.\r\nActivityId: 3cf6769d-fe56-40ca-832d-305820ef78e1, documentdb-dotnet-sdk/2.14.0 Host/64-bit MicrosoftWindowsNT/10.0.19041.0\nRequestID:3cf6769d-fe56-40ca-832d-305820ef78e1\n"
        }
    }
}
```

Though the following will return me results:

```
https://{{databaseAccount}}.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/Rdm()?$top=1&$select=PartitionKey
```

Gives:

```
{
    "value": [
        {
            "odata.etag": "W/\"datetime'2022-01-01T14%3A07%3A54.8052493Z'\"",
            "PartitionKey": "8"
        }
    ]
}
```

Is there some weird little header that is required to do filtering?

Clearly Authorisation is working, otherwise headers sent are:-

```
Accept: application/json
x-ms-version: 2021-06-08
x-ms-date: Fri, 06 May 2022 17:14:30 GMT
Authorization: SharedKey {{databaseAccount}}:gargbagebutitdoesappeeartotherwisework
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.29.0
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: 0e09a9e8-210d-4b6f-a258-efe6963bff39
Host: {{databaseAccount}}.table.cosmos.azure.com:443
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Connection: keep-alive
```

The signature is composed of:

```
verb + \n + \n + \n + dateUtc + \n + /{{databaseAccount}}/{{table}}
```

where table in this case = Rdm()

Comment: Can you try by url encoding the filter criteria? Something like `https://{{databaseAccount}}.table.cosmos.azure.com:443/Rdm()?$filter=PartitionKey%20eq%20'726'`.

Comment: It gets sent out encoded from postman; though I did also try to encode it

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I needed to add the header - MaxDataServiceVersion: 3.0;NetFx

Eventually found the answer in GitHub https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-go/issues/1020

It's also quite clearly stated in their documentation - doh.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/setting-the-odata-data-service-version-headers

> When you call one of these operations, you must specify the OData data
> service version, using one of the following request headers:
>
> MaxDataServiceVersion, to specify the maximum data service version
>
> DataServiceVersion, to specify the exact data service version
>
> If both headers are present, precedence is given to
> MaxDataServiceVersion